# After deploying the site and taking it down , firebase is not getting updated for the localhost changes

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I deployed my website and tested firebase and all worked well. But now I need to modify the code but firebase is not reflecting the changes I made.I stoppped the server as well . How do I get firebase to show changes of the localhost.Thank you in advance

Comment: To deploy the local changes to Firebase Hosting's servers, re-run `firebase deploy`.

Comment: Firebase started reflecting changes after several hours. i didnt have to do anything .But thank you for the reply.